# Doctrine - Reverse join on an entity symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

i have an issue.
I am using a Bundle to store everything related to the hardware of my company (including name of each VM, which application this component is running etc) and i have another that adds its own information to these machines. The first one is called CMDB and the second is called PSI.

The PSI Bundle depends of the CMDB bundle but the opposite is false.

One of the entity in the CMDB bundle is the codeSA, representing an application code. 
BUT in the PSI bundle, i want to add that for each codeSA, there is a Perimeter. A perimeter has multiple codeSA.

I want to get all the informatiosn related to a component. i can fetch its codeSA without any issue. But i also want to get its perimeter ! How can i do this since the codeSA CAN'T know its perimeter i cant put an relation to perimeter in the codeSA entity !

What i did is using a manytomany operation in the perimeter, like this
 :

```
 /**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="G\GMOBundle\Entity\Application")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="gmo_psi_perimetre_sa",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="perimetre_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="codeSA_id", referencedColumnName="id_SYSTEME_APPLICATIF")}
 *      )
 */
private $codeSA;
```

There is the querybuilder i am using :

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->join('a.composant','comp')
        ->join('comp.correspondanceApplications', 'corr')
        ->join('corr.systemeApplicatif','cs') //this is the codeSA table
        ->join('GGMOPSIBundle:Perimetre','p','WITH','cs.id = p.codeSA') //i want to get my perimetre
```

But i get an

> near 'codeSA WHERE': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

Plus when i will get my entity , i can go to the codeSA like : entuity.composant.correspondanceApplications.systemeApplicatif , but how can i access the perimeter?

Hope i am clear enough. Do not hesitate to ask for more code.

Thanks !

Comment: What's 'a'? `G\GMOBundle\Entity\Application`? Please show your entity model.